# Using c to insert variables in mysql database

Tags: mysql, c

I am trying to insert variable calculated in my C program using mysql API . Despite trying all types of tricks( single quote , double quotes , query placeholder)  I am not able to enter the data. The libraries used are:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <my_global.h>
 #include <mysql.h>
```

The relevant bits of code are

```
MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "test", "test123", 
      "transport", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) 
{
   finish_with_error(con);
}    
if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO gps_points(vehicle_id,lat,lon,speed) VALUES(unit_id_dec,lat,lon,speed_float)")) 
{
   finish_with_error(con);
}
mysql_close(con);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Unknown column 'unit_id_dec' in 'field list'
```

The compile options used are:

```
sudo gcc socketListen.c -o listenSock -lm `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-prepared-statement-function-overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched and found that following solution is working :

```
char buf[1024] = {};
char query_string[] = { 
   "INSERT INTO gps_points(vehicle_id,lat,lon,speed) VALUES(%u,%.4f,%.4f,%.2f)" 
                      };
sprintf(buf, query_string,unit_id_dec,lat,lon,speed_float);
if (mysql_query(con,buf)) 
{
  finish_with_error(con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error you will need either rewrite trigger and remove 'unit_id_dec' variable or alter table and add variable 'unit_id_dec'.

[Here's link how to rewrite trigger.](https://www.psce.com/blog/2015/07/16/unobvious-unknown-column-in-field-list-error/)

Comment: unit_id_dec is the variable whose value needs to be inserted. It is not a column